# How do I force a file download in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a .exe that users must install for a piece of hardware on my website. I am currently storing this .exe in my storage/app/public folder and have ensured that both the file and the folders have permissions to be accessed.

I have run `php artisan storage:link`

And currently use:

```
public function Downloadfile(Request $request)
{
    Log::debug("DOWNLOADFILE");
    $path = storage_path().'\\app\\public\\'.'file.exe';
    Log::debug("Path ".$path);
    Log::debug(file_exists($path));
    
    return Storage::download($path);
}
```

This results in the following.

[image: An image of a log file describing the results of the debug messages]

The file EXISTS, as the logs say, but for some reason, when I try to download it, I cannot do so.

Comment: When trying to figure out paths or strings, try testing in Laravel Tinker, it can save you loads of time: php artisan tinker.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have your path wrong.  You need to get rid of:

```
app/public
```

In the Laravel config/filesystems.php there is usually this:

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

So

The 'storage' sym link in the public folder is a sym link to storage/app/public.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

At least with my setup, my profile photos are in: public/profile-photos, and the url to those is:

```
storage/profile-photos/bIlkdsTMTJFjiBDoarcQcfxWutJ0BvktYDQ7dcjU.jpg
```

so you probably need:

C:\Usersxxx.source\repos\xxx\storage\file.exe

You just need to adjust the path.  Try that.

Comment: I see that a link has been created to `public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public')` but when I change the path like you mentioned, I get the same issue and the if_exists debug message shows false.

Comment: OK.  The symlink "storage" in the public folder is to serve content in the storage/app/public via a URL, like for the profile images.  $path = storage_path().'\\app\\public\\'.'file.exe' should be the absolute path to your file.

Comment: Maybe read this:  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-use-storagedownload?page=1&replyId=511385

i ended up using response()->download(file) or return Storage::disk('public')->download($file->path);